# How to sorting nodes along with their following siblings in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to sort an XML file by a child element value using XSLT. The sorting element has a following sibling should always be after it.

The XSLT I have done so far:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />

        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::city | self::cityNumber)]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="city">
            <xsl:sort select="text()" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The XML file looks like:

```
<parent>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <name>Alice</name>
    <another-attribute>something</another-attribute>
    <city>B.111Kansas City</city>
    <cityNumber>1</cityNumber>
    <city>A.123Atlanta</city>
    <cityNumber>2</cityNumber>
</parent>
```

I expect the output:

```
<parent>
   <name>Bob</name>
   <name>Alice</name>
   <another-attribute>something</another-attribute>
   <city>A.123Atlanta</city>
   <cityNumber>2</cityNumber>
   <city>B.111Kansas City</city>
   <cityNumber>1</cityNumber>
</parent>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::city or self::cityNumber)]" />
        <xsl:for-each select="city">
            <xsl:sort/>
            <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::cityNumber[1]" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, an additional question is that if there are more than one <cityNumber> element after a <city> element? Like 
`<city>Atlanta</city>
<cityNumber>1</cityNumber>
<cityNumber>2</cituNumber>`

Comment: Then it gets complicated. Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes, what do you suggest? ( I want to be clear that the occurrence of  <cityNumber> is random, I may need to get all the <cityNumber> until meeting the next <city> element.) Thanks!

Comment: If you can use XSLT 2.0, then do `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-starting-with="city"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several `cityNumber` you want to sort together with the `city` elements you could use `<xsl:for-each-group select="city | cityNumber" group-starting-with="city">` and sort the groups:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="parent">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (city, cityNumber)"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="city | cityNumber" group-starting-with="city">
              <xsl:sort/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfL

Comment: It shows exactly the result I want, it's just I am not familiar with XSLT 3.0. I will look into it! Thank you so much.

Comment: There is no specific XSLT 3 code in there other than `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`, the rest should do with XSLT 2 as well. And that `xsl:mode` declaration can be replaced by `<xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>` in XSLT 2.